# HTML image slideshow shows a blank screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I do not have much experience with html but I need to setup a image slideshow on my site. I found this bit of code on w3schools but after adding media query it shows a blank screen in between the images. How do i get rid of it and have just back to back images only? Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

  #web {
    display: none;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  #mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}


</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="w3-content w3-section" id="web">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/126849-v6-honor-10-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/64428999/Vivo-NEX.jpg" style="width:100%">
 
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" id="mobile">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://japan-magazine.jnto.go.jp/jnto2wm/wp-content/uploads/1603_iwate_main.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/panoramic-view-idyllic-mountain-scenery-260nw-622792952.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 1;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For your x you have it grabbing all "mySlides" elements. What is that number giving you when you step through your code?

Comment: A bit of advice, stay as far away from W3 Schools as you can. It's well-known to have incomplete, outdated and flat out wrong information. Instead, learn from [The Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All indexes start with 0. So change initial index in your `for` loop to 0 and get it work. Also you have to change classNames for your images in the mobile version (it's why you got blank pages after a few images shown) and you implemented wrong media queries.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  if(screen.width <= 480){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides_mobile");
  }else{
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000);
}
```

```css
.mySlides, .mySlides_mobile {
  display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #web {
    display: none;
  } 
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   #mobile {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

</head>

<body>


<div class="w3-content w3-section" id="web">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.91-img.com/pictures/126849-v6-honor-10-mobile-phone-large-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/64428999/Vivo-NEX.jpg" style="width:100%">
 
</div>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" id="mobile">
  <img class="mySlides_mobile" src="https://japan-magazine.jnto.go.jp/jnto2wm/wp-content/uploads/1603_iwate_main.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides_mobile" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/panoramic-view-idyllic-mountain-scenery-260nw-622792952.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver. Didn't realize there were so many things wrong with it! Thanks again!